# Ricky Gervais used an odd word like benign but about being complacent in a group discussion

Tags: single-word-requests

I can't exactly remember where it was from, it was during an interview or perhaps an episode of the Ricky Gervais Show, where he was talking about how not speaking what's on your mind or being complacent all the time in a group discussion leads to your original point or idea becoming blunted or watered down by the averaging of the group.. does anyone know what's that word I'm trying to recall? thanks

Comment: Are you sure it starts with the letter *b*?

Comment: no it definitely didn't start with 'b' but it sounded or felt similar to it...
I think it started with an 'a' but gosh for the life of me I can't recollect the word!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it sounded like *benign* but didn't start with *b* then perhaps the word you're thinking of is ***anodyne.***

> Not likely to cause offence or disagreement and somewhat dull:
>   *anodyne music*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/anodyne)

I'm not sure that "complacent" fits that, nor that it is the action of a group, but using anodyne language would certainly blunt or water down your own expressions of opinion.

Comment: that's it! That's the word! thank you mate! god it's been driving me mad all morning!

Comment: The interview in question is here: http://www.theguardian.com/culture/2010/jul/18/ricky-gervais-comedy-interview

Comment: heh, it's a good word

Comment: Bingo, and that's the interview I was watching/reading. cheers lads, a pint to the both of you!